# Any tutorials on how to encrypt a file using triple des on eclipse ? (dropbox)

Tags: java, android

Is there any references or tutorials on how to encrypt the files using triple des when uploaded to dropbox ?

I will be using Eclipse software to do. So is there any good tutorials and good explanation on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this [tutorial](http://sanjaal.com/java/189/java-encryption/tutorial-encryption-and-decryption-using-desede-triple-des-in-java/) . Here you can find code to encrypt and decrypt.

After encrypt you can upload it to dropbox.

It does not matter if you use Eclipse or netbin.

Comment: What if I want to encrypt a file instead of the password that is stated in the website? How should i do it? Any help? thank you .

Comment: A file can probably be read as a string of binary digits (lots of 1's and 0's). You could read the file, then encrypt the string using DES the same way you would a password, outputting the result to a new file.

Decryption would work the same way, reading the encrypted file, decrypting, and outputting to an unencrypted file.

Comment: search tutorial for read data from file and write data into file

Comment: This ? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

Have to combine this codes with that tutorial that you gave me right?

Comment: hmm hello chirag raval do u know by any chance about this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12315043/encrypt-the-file-before-uploading-to-dropbox. Need help on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of Java Triple DES: http://eternusuk.blogspot.de/2008/09/java-triple-des-example.html

It does not matter if you use Eclipse, its an IDE, not a platform.